# SQL print subqueries' selected value

Tags: sql

The query below works talking about its functionality, but I wanted to select the result of the multiplication too, as you can see:

```
SELECT
    I.Nome, I.Cognome, I.Stipendio, GP 
FROM
    Impiegati I 
WHERE 
    I.Stipendio >= ALL(SELECT (progetti.Budget * partecipazioni.Percentuale / 100) AS GP /*HERE*/
                       FROM Partecipazioni, Progetti  
                       WHERE Partecipazioni.CodProgetto = Progetti.CodProgetto 
                         AND I.ID = partecipazioni.ID) 
ORDER BY 
    I.Nome ASC;
```

I get this error:

> Unknown column 'GP' in 'field list'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the logic to the `from` clause in order to return the value.  The equivalent logic is basically:

```
select I.Nome, I.Cognome, I.Stipendio, pp.GP
from Impiegati I join
     (select id, max(pr.Budget * pa.Percentuale / 100) as GP
      from Partecipazioni pa join
           Progetti pr
           on pa.CodProgetto = pr.CodProgetto
      group by pa.id
     ) pp
     on I.ID = pp.ID
where I.Stipendio >= pp.gp
```

The only difference is if there are no matches in the subquery (the query can be tweaked for this case if necessary).

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
Edit: Fixed the displayed error.

Comment: `I.ID = p.ID` --> `I.ID = pp.ID`

Comment: Correct, plus an "ON" was missing, thank you both :)